# JIRA+Crowd: how to allow users to change their own passwords?

Tags: jira, crowd

So I just got JIRA running with Crowd. How do I allow users to change their own passwords? I must be missing something obvious.

I have a test account, I can login to JIRA but I don't see any way to change my password, and I can't login to Crowd via that test account.

Comment: Do you not have support through Atlassian? I've been *very* happy with their tech support.

Comment: i do, but serverfault/stackoverflow etc. is great for really really quick answers for seemingly obvious stuff (of which this seemed to be the case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CROWD: Changing or Resetting your Password](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWD/Changing+or+Resetting+your+Password), found from [CROWD: Crowd 101](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWD/Crowd+101), has some details.

Comment: This didn't help me. I don't seem to have a way in my crowd (2.7) to "set the 'Allow All to Authenticate' option to 'True'"

Comment: Actually i'm not sure if its 2.7 - the help link goes to the docs for 2.7 tho

Answer (score 0):

aha, found it in [Atlassian documentation](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWD/Granting+Crowd+User+Rights+to+a+User). You have to grant entire directory access to crowd, every user in it can then change their own password. If you grant access to crowd with a group, that group gets admin rights to crowd, which is NOT a good idea.

Dunno why they can't allow finer grains of access.